# How do I unzip multiple files with multiple passwords in 7zipfull on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm kind of a beginner in Linux and I'm having a hard time. On Ubuntu 19.10, I made a small script for 7zip to unzip multiple files with password:

```bash
FILES=/mnt/sdx
for f in *.7z;
do 7za x -oUNZIPPED $f -ppassowrd;
done
```

It works perfectly for one password, but the point is, if I download an older file from the site that has the compressed files it uses another password so the program doesn't open, then I have to make another script for another password to work.

What I would like to know is if you can't integrate these old passwords into the script, like if he tries with one password and the file doesn't unzip, it tries with another password until the file sucsessfully unzip or until the available passwords are over.

Another thing, some older files are in .rar. How can I expand the script search for these two files?

---

Update: It finaly Worked!!! Thanks guys for the help and the patience the Final Script Looks Like This:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.{7z,zip,rar}
do
  for password in Pass1 Pass2 Pass3
  do
    7z x -oOUTPUTDIR -p"${password}" "${file}" && break
  done
done
```

I took the code that you gave me and add a minor modification, Thanks Again!!

Comment: i saw this comand line:
"for Z_FILE in *.zip; do
for PASSWD in [ pass123, PASS123, abc123, ABC123 ]; do
unzip -P $PASSWD $Z_FILE;
if [ $? = 0 ]; then # successful unzip
break
fi
done
done"
In a post with folows this link: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-unzipping-many-zip-files/
But i don't know hot to adapt this to mys script.

Comment: You want to do the following: an outer `for`-loop for all files, an inner `for`-loop for all passwords. `break` the inner loop, if the extraction succeeds: `7za x -oDIR -p"${passw}" "${file}" && break`. a && b = if successful termination a-command, do b-command. Please also try to edit your question to make your code readable.  [Markdown help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)

Comment: sorry, can you be more clear? I couldn't understand I dont know how to make more readble, i'm new in the forum. I can try to take a screenshot if helps

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what you have achieved so far and what your reference source means. Please format your question accordingly, otherwise it cannot be answered. My hints for your goal: Nested do-loops (outer runs though filenames, inner through passwords), the inner loop will break (this is a bash command - look it up!) when a password successfully is used to unzip a file (so that the other passwords will not be tried on that file and the next file will be tried). Check the following `bash` commands and operators: `for ...  do ; done` (nested), `break`, `&&`, `||`.

Comment: At the current Time i Manage to make this:
FILES=/mnt/sdax  <br/>
 for f in * .7z, .zip, .rar;  <br/>
   do 7za x -oUNZIPPED $f -ppassword;  <br/>
 done  <br/>
The program is able to find the formats, but i'm stil having some dificulties to make the program use the others passwords.

Comment: What is the `FILES=` meant to do? it has no connection to your `for` loop. Use ` to embed code in comments and four spaces in front of code blocks for question and answers. [As stated here in the MARKDOWN HELP](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)

Comment: Dude I really don't know, I found the code and modified to work with 7za, I believe that makes part the line to found the folder that the program will look for the zipped files. And, I'm reading the help thai you posted to write the codes correctly but isn't working. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

A possible script - save this in a file called e.g. 7za_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.7z
do
  for password in pass1 pass2 pass3
  do
    7za x -oOUTPUTDIR -p"${password}" "${file}" && break
  done
done
```

What does it do?

**1. The outer loop `for file in *.7z`**

We define the variable called `file` to any entry in your current working directory that ends in `.7z`. The `*` hereby is a wildcard that is expanded to zero or any number of characters. `*.7z` will thus match anythng that has a `7zip` suffix. The loop now runs once per match and we can refer to the match of the current loop run via `$file`, i.e. calling a variable.

**2. The inner loop `for password in pass1 pass2 pass3`**

In this loop we define tha variable `password` by explicitely stating three optional values `pass1`, `pass2`, and `pass3`. The loop will run once for each value.

**3. The `7za`-command**

Try to extract the current file from our list with the given password. For each `$file` all three `$password` possibilities are tried. The order of nested loops is such that the inner loop will always be run fully before going to the next step in the outer loop.

**4. The `&& break` part**

`break` will stop a loop run of the innermost loop. Thus if we call `break` in the password loop after trying `pass1` the `pass2` and `pass3` option will not even be tried. The question is when NOT to try other passwords. Simple: upon successfully extracting a file with `pass1` the other passwords need not to be tried for that file.

Each command has an `exit status` that is either `0` for success or any other number for `fail` (the actual value of the number can give more information about what went wrong, but this depends on the individual program). `man 7za` shows under `DIAGNOSTICS`:

> > 0      Normal (no errors or warnings detected)
> >
> > 1      Warning (Non fatal error(s)). For example, some files cannot be read during compressing, so they were not compressed
> >
> > 2      Fatal error

Thus if a file is successfully extracted, the exit code should be `0` and if a password does not unlock it, it should be `2`. You can get the exit status of a previous command by `echo $?`. Just try `echo $?` after running `true` or `false` (commands that either always succeed or always fail).

Now `&& command` means "run command if the previous command was successful (exit status = `0`). So what we do is: if `$password` unlocked `$file` (and no other error occured), we `break` the password-loop, as there is no reason for trying the other passwords on that file. Instead we can now go on to the next file.

**5. Running the script**

Once you saved the script as e.g. `7za_script.sh` and wrote the passwords in there as you need them, you can run it via `bash 7za_script.sh` OR make it executable with `chmod +x 7za_script.sh` and run it via `./7za_script.sh`.

**6. Notes**

- The script is very simplistic, but just meant as a basic start for your scripting career.
- Move it to your desired directory and execute it.
- It will not differ between a file called `1.7za` or a directory `2.7za` (that is obviously not a zipped thing at all but just shares the name). Testing this would be the next step.
- It is very unsafe to store passwords in a clear text file, but it seems to be a low security problem in the first place.
- Quoting `"` and calling variables as `${var}` instead of `$var` make scripts more stable in case of e.g. spaces in filenames. I'll not go more into detail here but leave the keywords: hard quotes, soft quotes, shell variables
- `&&` and `||` are called *OPERATORS*
- Take this as a start, try to understand what it does and enjoy scripting.

Comment: It worked for the .7z files, if i want to unzip the .rar and .zip files in the same code what i have to do?

Comment: Check out how the wildcard selects `7z`-files. How could you add wildcards for other suffixes?

Comment: the program recognizes the .rar files but still it not being able to unzip the .rar files, for 7z works like a charm, I have the extensions for .rar files installed but I believe these files don't use 7za to uncompress. When I run the program for .rar files, it gives me back an error "Can not open the file as archive"

Comment: `7za` is a reduced but faster version of `7z` which might not handle rar. Try using `7z` instead of `7za`.

Comment: Something strange is happening, the program keeps trying no extract all files in the folder including the files that are not in the extensions previously established. I don't know why.

Comment: Computers never do strange things, people just give strange commands. I assume you made a `*` wildcard that matches all files?

Comment: It's fixed, in fact was a syntax error. I was messing up with the spaces in the line, fixed this and work like a charm. I don't know how I refer you in the post, but my sincere thank you for all the help and the patience.